# AppCenter Rejection due to SSO

Tags: ios, facebook

our application have been rejected from the Facebook App Center because of this:
"Your iOS app does not appear to use Single Sign-On (SSO). Please either implement SSO or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app."

But we have SSO implemented. Is it a mistake? Should we just resubmit the app?

Comment: Do you have the iOS details in your app settings? it could be that whoever checked your app wasn't brought through the SSO flow

Comment: from my experience once an app is submitted you will generally get the same reviewer.  So i dont think resubmitting will help,

Comment: did you leave a reviewer reply? What did they say?

Comment: @PaulCezanne Is it possible to leave a reply? I cannot see any form to fill.... Igy, we have SSO details

Comment: Submit a YouTube video with the app usage to them in the review notes. This works much better than any screenshots etc. Worked smoothly in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Wow it's weird that they gave you this answer before the announcement.

Either it could be one of two scenarios:

- Implement this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso

and/or

- Implement the Facebook API's now part of the new SDK